# On Mac OS X 10.11 nvcc doesn't like complex if used with .cu extension

Tags: c, macos, cuda, nvcc

I have a simple code which compiles differently depending whether it's saved with .c or .cu extension:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>

int main()
{
    float num;
    float eps_i, eps_s, tau_d, sigma;
    float pi, wave_freq, eps_0;

    eps_i = 43.0;
    eps_s = 2.4;
    tau_d = 0.3;
    sigma = 4.75;
    pi = 3.14;
    wave_freq = 0.015;
    eps_0 = 40.234;

    float complex c1 = 0.0 + 2.0 * pi * wave_freq * tau_d * I;
    float complex c2 = 0.0 + sigma / (2.0 * pi * wave_freq * eps_0) * I;

    num = creal(eps_i + (eps_s - eps_i) / (1.0 + (0.0 + 2.0 * pi * wave_freq * tau_d * I)) -
    (0.0 + sigma / (2.0 * pi * wave_freq * eps_0) * I));

    printf("%g\n", num);
}
```

If I compile it using `nvcc test.c` it works exactly how I expected it. However if I run `nvcc test.cu` I get:

```
test.cu(18): error: expected a ";"

test.cu(19): error: "complex" has already been declared in the current scope

test.cu(19): error: expected a ";"

test.cu(21): error: identifier "I" is undefined

test.cu(21): error: identifier "creal" is undefined

test.cu(18): warning: variable "complex" was declared but never referenced

test.cu(19): warning: variable "complex" was declared but never referenced

5 errors detected in the compilation of "/var/folders/3z/8bl4b3yx0c3_5tgf35dr_z180000gp/T//tmpxft_00015a75_00000000-9_test.cpp1.ii".
```

I understand that .cu is treated as code containing CUDA code and .c is just host code, but I would expect them to behave the same in this instance. Notice that it doesn't complain about `#include <complex.h>` at all. What am I missing?

Comment: `float` vs `double` and `c1` and `c2` are not used at all. Turn on your compiler settings and fix them.

Comment: That is completely irrelevant to my question

Comment: No is not `test.cu(18): warning: variable "complex" was declared but never referenced`, any way did you tried `-cuda` ?

Comment: `.cu` is not just Host code, contains the device functions too.

Comment: I'm not asking about the warnings, I'm asking about the errors. `-cuda` is implied when you compile source with .cu extension.

Comment: There is no errors/warnings when i compile it with `nvcc program.cu`, i just fixed the warnings and worked fine.

Comment: When I compile this with a .cu extension using each of CUDA 4.2, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5, 7.0 and 7.5, there are no errors generated

Comment: Have you set any additional flags or anything? I'm using CUDA 7.5 on OS X 11.11, maybe it's something to do my environment?

Comment: I didn't. I have Ubuntu 15.04 (64BIT) with `Cuda compilation tools, release 6.5, V6.5.12`

Comment: @Rafal: No flags, no nothing. The host compiler I have is gcc 4.6.3

Comment: @Rafal: Are you sure that El Capitan is acutally supported in CUDA 7.5?

Comment: @talonmies It is supported, Nvidia's website shows it as download for Mac OS X 10. 11. It's odd because everything else works perfectly fine except for complex.h functions and macros. Maybe it's linked against wrong library or something along that way.

Comment: I would file a bug report if I were you

Answer (score 1):

From comments, this problem would appear to be specific to CUDA 7.5 on OS X El Capitan with the latest XCode. The provided repro case seems to work on every other platform it was tested on. It has been recommended that a bug report be raised with NVIDIA.

[This answer has been added as a community wiki entry to get this question off the unanswered list]